# populate blocks of html code dependant on select option value

Tags: jquery

I have a select box where by the user can select how many people they want to select to register. For example if 4 is selected then 4 people registration areas appear below in a form:

jQuery:

```
var person = '<div class="reg-person"><span class="person">Person 1</span><div class="field"><label for="name">name</label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></div><div class="field"><label for="company">company</label><input type="text" id="company" name="company" /></div><div class="field"><label for="email">email address</label><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /></div><div class="field"><label for="contact">contact number</label><input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" /></div></div>';

            var peopleDisplayed = 0;

            $('.places-req').change(function() {
                if(peopleDisplayed == 0) {
                    peopleDisplayed = ($(this).val());
                    numberPeople = ($(this).val());
                    for(var i = 1 ; i <= numberPeople ; i++){
                        $('#register').prepend(person);
                    }
                } else {
                    var peopleDiff = ($(this).val() - peopleDisplayed);
                    if (peopleDiff > 0) {
                        for(var i = 1 ; i <= peopleDiff ; i++){
                            $('#register').prepend(person);
                        }
                    } else if (peopleDiff < 0) {
                        var diff = -peopleDiff;
                        for(var i = 1 ; i <= diff ; i++){
                            $('#register').children('div.person').last().remove();
                        }
                    }
                    peopleDisplayed = ($(this).val());
                }

            });
```

The html is:

```
<form id="register" action="/event/scripts/register.html" method="post">


                        <div class="submit-field">
                            <input type="hidden" value="1" id="event" name="event" />
                            <input type="submit" value="" />
                        </div>
                        <p>* Please note that we will not pass your details to a third party.</p>
                    </form>
```

My question is how can i amend the code so that for each person it shows Person 1, Person 2 etc... At the moment they all show as person 1. I'll also need to use this number to use with the form field names so that they are different, name1, name2 etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how to comment but the answer is on this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/CQg8L/

```
parseInt(parseInt(peopleDisplayed)+i)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `i` inside `for` loop to have Person1 , Person2 ...

```
$('#register').prepend('<div class="reg-person"><span class="person">Person '+i+' </span><div class="field"><label for="name">name</label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></div><div class="field"><label for="company">company</label><input type="text" id="company" name="company" /></div><div class="field"><label for="email">email address</label><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /></div><div class="field"><label for="contact">contact number</label><input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" /></div></div>');
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Trouble with that is when I change the amount in the select box from 2 to 3 it displays 3 people registration boxes but as person 1, person 2, person 1. I need the value of 'i' to carry on from the last  number of people counter if that makes sense?

Comment: @Rob . Can you update this fiddle to show your problem - http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/Y5bnB/

Comment: Do you see the problem from the fiddle Mohammad?